# Making random animations on JQuery without collapsing with random number calcullation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, random, scroll

I´m tring to make some images appear when you scroll and I want the animations they were random.

I have this:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    /* Check the location of each desired element */

    $('.conferencia').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( (bottom_of_window) > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({opacity:'1'},{duration:1500, queue: false});
            randomAnim($(this).find("img"));

        }

    });

});
```

I don´t know if this part it´s done correctly, the images don't appear exactly when bottom of window is on the bottom of object.

Now I have the function randomAnim() that selects form a animation pull:

```
function randomAnim(element){

    switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1) {
    case 1:
        element.css({'transform':'rotateX(360deg)'});
        break;
    case 2:
        element.css({'transform':'rotateZ(360deg)'});
        break;
    case 3:
        element.css({'transform':'rotateY(360deg)'});
        break;
    }
}
```

With this code the animation is not executing but if I place an *alert(1)* before every *break;* the animation works so I suppose that the problem is that Math.random calculates too much numbers and this collapses, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: I add that fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4qfgz0z9/1/ 
It's not exactly the same behaviour but I think so it can help. I realized that if you scroll a bit and stop the animation randomly works or not but if you scroll and scroll the animation doesn't work. Another problem is that animations repeat over and over instead doing it just once when the object appears.

Comment: Your math is fine--the expression in your switch statement will produce an integer between 1 and 3, inclusive. It's more likely that you've got some timing issues between the jQuery animations and the CSS animation. Placing the `alert` before your `randomAnim` returns changes the timing of the animations. Add an example or fiddle that demonstrates the problem. Also consider using CSS animations and simply adding/removing a class on the container based on scroll position.

Comment: I added a fiddle. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a lock and the animation now works, so might be setting css multiple times may clean existing transition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animated = []

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    $('div').each(function(i) {
      if (animated[i]) {
        return
      }

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if ((bottom_of_window) > bottom_of_object) {
        animated[i] = true
        $(this).animate({
          opacity: '1'
        }, {
          duration: 1500,
          queue: false
        });
        randomAnim($(this));
      }

    });

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3v2jcqqg/